# Rails 3.1 -- Can't mass assign protected attributes (even though added to attr_accessible)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a nested form `categories` for `stores` and have it listed as attr_accessible in the store model. But still keep getting the following error:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category_ids
```

I've tried all variations of attr_accessible in the store model:

```
attr_accessible :categories
attr_accessible :category
attr_accessible :category_id
attr_accessible :category_ids
```

None of them work! Both these models are has_and_belongs_to_many (and have a joining table called categories_stores).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated (I've been banging my head against the wall for two days over this).

**UPDATE**

I've implemented a **temporary fix** (which is pretty redundant and not needed if rails just adhered to the above problem). I fixed it by overwriting the `create` method for ActiveAdmin and looping to insert the association data:

```
  controller do
    def update
      @store = store.find(params[:id])
      if @store.update_attributes(params[:store])
        @store.categories.delete_all
        params[:store][:category_ids].each do |category_id|
          @store.categories << Category.find(category_id) unless category_id.blank?
        end
        redirect_to :action => :index
      else
        redirect_to :action => :edit, :notice => "Something f'ed up"
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: I've even tried removing attr_accessible for both models and still no go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if you have a joining table called categories_stores, that your assignments will be more along the lines of:

```
class Store

    has_many :categories, :through => :categories_stores
```

with a similar setup in the Categories model.

In your form, if you are creating a store, say, and you want to create / add categories for that store, then you may also need to add:

```
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories_stores
```

to be able to add to that table.

You can read more about nested attributes here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I've had this same problem too, and the only solution I could find is what Stephanie suggested.  E.g. switch to a has_many :through, and manage nested attribute CRUD for the join association, (store_categories) rather then the categories assocation.